# Expressing an formula in term of another one

Tags: algebra-precalculus, equivalence-relations, lambert-w

I have this formula

$$-\frac 1\lambda\left[\lambda D+1+W_{-1}\left(-r\exp(-\lambda D-1)\right)\right]$$

with $r$ , $\lambda$ and $D$ >0.

Where $W$ is the Lambert W function http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function

I have some reason to believe that this expression is somehow equivalent to a simple:

$$\gamma+\alpha x^\beta $$
where $\beta<0$, $\alpha$  and $\gamma >0 $.

I believe this just because from numerical simulation I can almost perfectly fit the second equation starting from the first one, treating $\lambda$ as $x$, as shown in the figure[image]
The blue circles represent the first equation, the solid black line represent the second one, fitted over the first one. The fit is not perfect, but it is pretty good, and it is still good when I play around with the different parameters.
So, I am wondering: are these two equations the same? If so, how can I prove that?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Technically, not an equation, but a formula. An equation always has an equality sign in it, and is always a question: For what values is this true?

Comment: changed it, sorry for the mistake.

Comment: Not a mistake, you just weren't talking about equations, and just adding an equals sign doesn't make it "an equation." The error was calling them equations, not failing to have an equality.

Comment: Do you know that $D>0$?

Comment: Wait, $W$ is not defined for negative values, so is $r<0$?

Comment: r, D and lambda are positive. W is actually $W_{-1}$

Comment: @Vaaal: You said $\lambda=x$ in your approximation. Can you give us the ranges (or the values) of the other variables $r$ and $D$? Othrewise it's hard to tell.

Comment: Hi Ioannis. r, D and $\lambda$ are all $>0$. If you are asking the values used in the simulation, D=5 and r=1. Does this answer the question?

Comment: I'm not finding much on estimates for $W_{-1}$, but I'm guessing a simple substitution with an approximation for $W_{-1}(x)$ when $x$ is small will likely help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Thomas says, it would be nice to have an approximation of $W_{-1}(z)$ to replace it in the final function and have it over with.

Unfortunately the plain Taylor series expansion of the -1 branch of the Lambert is unsuited for this case, because the domain of the OP's function exceeds its radius of convergence.

If however, we use the compound expansion of $W_{-1}(-\exp(-5x-1))$ around approximately half the range of 0..8, we are in business (note that $-\exp(-5x-1)$, for $x\in(0,8)$, falls inside the domain $(-1/e,0)$ of the branch $k=-1$ of the Lambert, so such an expansion is valid).

The original function:

> W:=LambertW;
>
> f := proc (lambda) options operator, arrow; -(5*lambda+1+W(-1, -exp(-5*lambda-1)))/lambda end proc;

Using Maple and expanding the Lambert term around x=3, using $\mathit{only}$ 2 terms:

> s := series(W(-1, -exp(-5*x-1)), x = 3.0, 2);
>
> s := -18.94134722-5.278685871*(x-3.0)+O((x-3.0)^2)
>
> p := convert(s, polynom);
>
> sp2 := unapply(p, x):

Now substitute the series found in place of the Lambert term:

> g2 := proc (x) options operator, arrow; -(5*x+1+sp2(x))/x end proc;

Let's try it now:

> p1 := plot(f(x), x = 0 .. 8, 0 .. 6, color = red):
>
> p2 := plot(g2(x), x = 0 .. 8, 0 .. 6, color = green):
>
> display(p1, p2);

[image: comparison]

The approximation is now revealed as:

> simplify(g2(x));
>
> expand(%);
>
> .2786858710+2.105289610/x,

which can easily be seen as being of the form $\gamma+\alpha\cdot x^{\beta}$, with $\beta=-1<0$ and $\gamma,\alpha>0$.

Tweeking these constants a bit may make the match even better.

Comment: Thank you for your beautiful answer. So am I right in assuming that there is no way to express the parameters of the first formula in term of the par. of the second one?

Comment: @Vaaal: You are welcome. You could, if you repeated the above process in general, having as variables $D$ and $r$ and a free variable $\lambda$ (or $x$). The final $\gamma$ and $\alpha$ would of course be functions of your $D$ and $r$. For any such general calculation of the approximation, you should keep track of the quantity $-\lambda\cdot D-1$ and first make sure that for your $\lambda$ range, you are always falling inside the interval $(-1/e,0)$. Otherwise the approximation is not guaranteed to work and your final $\alpha$ and $\gamma$ may be nonsense.

Comment: Thank you Ioannis. I will take a closer look at your answer tomorrow, but in the meantime, can you tell me if there is any way that this formula can give a $\beta$ which is NOT -1?

Comment: @Vaaal: This formula no, but some other formula for $f(x)$ might. Try it on $f^{*}(x)=x^k\cdot f(x)$, for $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.